# SQL table, 2 columns and keys placement

Tags: sql, key

Here is a problem. I need to have 2 columns in a table both `varchar(50)`. First Column is name of certain thing within a certain group which is defined by the second column.

```
First column | Second Column
thingone     | group one
thingtwo     | group one
thingone     | group two
```

Above is an example which I want to achieve by having these to columns. And my question is how to place keys in order to do it. I know there is a easier way by having third column with id. But I am asking for possibilities looking similar to one above.

Comment: i format your table structure section but still there problem in last paragraph please make it more clear

Comment: Yeah, with some examples if possible

Comment: Provide more details regarding your problem. Hence from above description, no one can get any assumption.

Comment: niktrs already anwsered my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a primary key that contain's both columns.

Read the link's article http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/08/23/composite_primary_keys.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't store the name of your group in your table. You should create another table for groups, maybe called `Groups` and store your groups there, using `GroupId` and `GroupName` columns. Then in your main table, you should have a column named `GroupId` which only accepts the Id of the group, or technically speaking, is the `foreign key` to the `Groups` table.